# Как вырезать все слова из строки и оставить только те, которые идут после всех запятых [Python]

Tags: python, строки

Допустим, есть строка:

```
PC, Mobile, Example Name
```

В данном примере нужно получить

```
Example Name
```

из строки выше. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

простой сплит вам поможет.

```
a = "PC, Mobile, Example Name"
res = a.split(", ")[-1]
print(res)
```

> Example Name

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто

```py
a = "PC, Mobile, Example Name"
i = a[a.rfind(',')+1: ].strip()
print(i)
```

PS приложите свою попытку решения, напишу четче и объясню код

Comment: Сначала пробовал получить последнее слово. Но так как предложение может состоять из нескольких слов, у меня не очень получилось это реализовать. Сейчас понял что да как. Спасибо.

Comment: @dujor21 если бы вы приложили код, я бы вам описал вашу ошибку. Мой код тоже не универсален, но как поставлена задача, так и написан ответ=)